# Cannot set the value of read-only property 'executionData' for task ':addressallocation:jacocoTestDebugUnitTestReport'

Tags: android, jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin, jacoco-plugin, android-jacoco

Getting below error for Jacoco dependency after upgrading Gradle version to 7.4

> groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Cannot set the value of read-only property 'executionData' for task ':addressallocation:jacocoTestDebugUnitTestReport' of type org.gradle.testing.jacoco.tasks.JacocoReport.

Currently using dependency
`classpath 'com.dicedmelon.gradle:jacoco-android:0.1.1'`

Please suggest how to resolve this error.